задать массив случайных чисел
создать массив случайных чисел. Найти в нём те числа которые делятся на 5

Забыли последнюю часть — Сделать самостоятельно.

так нечестно(((

Что сделано? какая именно часть задания не получается?

ест уже написанная программа с массивом случайных чисел. в этом массиве нужно найти те числа которые делятся на 5.

А как вы на математике проверяли, делится ли число на другое?

Вы правы, именно нечестно просить сделать за вас ваше задание...

int main() { srand(time(0)); int arr[5] = {rand(), rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()}; bool result[5] = {}; for (int i=0; i<5; i++) result[i] = (arr % 5 == 0 && arr != 0) ? true : false; }
